# Using Symbol#to_proc with multiple procs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some ruby code that operates on an ActiveRecord object using a couple of methods, and the end game is to return the object itself.  I want to use two methods that have return values other than the object itself (boolean values).  I like using the shorthand Symbol#to_proc syntax, i.e.

```
Object.tap(&:do_work)
```

Is it possible to pass multiple procs? i.e.

```
Object.tap(&:do_work, &:do_more_work)
```

The above syntax does not work.  Is this possible or do I have to do something like:

```
Object.tap(&:do_work).tap(&:do_more_work)
```

Comment: You are correct that you will have to do it in multiple taps `Object.tap(&:do_work).tap(&:do_more_work)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a good architectural solution then you need to implement [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) stack for that.

Or you can do it like you mentioned above:

```
Object.tap(&:do_work).tap(&:do_more_work)
```